# How to use LoggerFactory to get logs in the data flow Apache Beam application?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, loggerfactory

I am running a Beam application on Google DataFlow and I am not able to see the info logs in the dataflow.

```java
public class Abc {
      private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Abc.class);
      public static void main(String[] args){
             // reading files from a topic
             LOG.info("read success");
             // transformation of data using another class e.g Def   
.
.
.
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except I am not able to see the log statements placed in the main class (in this case class `Abc`) in Dataflow logs.

However, I have similar log statement in class `Def` and they work fine and I can see them in dataflow pipeline logs.

Please help me to understand the issue and how can this be resolved.

Comment: Have you checked the `job log` tab from `Dataflow` UI ?